# Open order on MT4 from Python?

Tags: python, mql4, metatrader4, mt4

I have Python code that uses the MT5-Python integration to run a strategy and execute orders. It works fine for MT5 terminals, however one of my accounts is on a broker that only supports MT4.

My question is unique because I don't need to read pricing data at all. I already have the necessary information from the python code (stoploss, take profit, *when* to open the order), with the exception of balance size. I need to retrieve the balance of the MT4 account to calculate position size, but other than that I just need to submit an order using the existing parameters.

What would be the easiest way to do this? A way to connect a .py file to a simple .mql4 file? I have zero familiarity with MQL4